# beeline spool Hive puts special character instead of quote

Tags: hive, spool, beeline

I am exporting query results form hive using beeline, here is my command :

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://myhost.com:10000/mydb;principal=hive/myhost.COM'  --incremental=true --silent=true  --outputformat=dsv --disableQuotingForSV=true --delimiterForDSV=\, --showHeader=false --nullemptystring=true  -f myquery.hql --hiveconf DT_ID=${DT_ID} > ${spoolFile}
```

This is my query :

```
SELECT id, concat('"',c_name,'"'), app_name from mytab where dt_id='${hiveconf:DT_ID}';
```

But I get results like this, for fields having my field separator(,) in column value:

```
66,**^@**"(Chat\, Social\, Music\, Utilities)"**^@**,Default
```

Note the **^@**. Why is it coming? How can avoid it? What is that character? If it is quote, I am  to have it, so that I can remove the concat in my query. I tried playing with `--disableQuotingForSV=true/false`. But that did not help me.

Comment: I removed the ^@ after creating the spool file using sed as temporary solution.